# Generate temperature data for a day using max and min temperatures

Tags: c

I need to generate temperature , humidity data for one day , using the maximum and minimum  temperature value , i need to generate data which goes like a sin wave , so here is what ive tried

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main ()
{
    int i;
    srand(time(NULL));
    #define randnum(min, max) \
        ((rand() % (int)(((max) + 1) - (min))) + (min))
    double time_min_temp=randnum(1494808200,1494802800);
    double time_max_temp=randnum(1494842400,1494846000);
    double MIN_TEMP=randnum(24,17);
    double MAX_TEMP=randnum(36,41);
    double diff = MAX_TEMP-MIN_TEMP;
    double time_diff = time_max_temp-time_min_temp;
    FILE *fp;char* filename;
    filename="data12.csv";
    fp=fopen(filename,"w+");
    fprintf(fp,"Time , Value");
    double output_range = 180 - 0;

     for(i=0;i<3600*24*10;i=i+3)
     {
        fprintf(fp,"\n");
        double temp = MAX_TEMP - diff*sin(i*90*0.0174533/time_diff);
        double time = time_max_temp+i;
        int rand1 = randnum(1,100);
        if (rand1<5) {//to create glitch in data
            double rand2 = randnum(0,10);
            rand2-=5;
            temp += temp*rand2/1000.0;
        }
        fprintf(fp,"%f",time);
        fprintf(fp,",%f",temp);
     }

}
```

Created to create temperature data , for 10 days , but im not convinced its like a perfect graph , is there any other way to accomplish this ?and even for the humidity i applied this same logic , im not getting correct values.

Comment: So, you are asking us to design and run tests against a spec that you have not fully defined?  'im not convinced its like a perfect graph' Why are you not convinced?  What tests did you run on the output?

Comment: @ThingyWotsit As the obtained data generates a perfect sin wave everyday, i need make it look like a real time temeperature and humidity data which is not a perfect sin wave